# Code behind does not get called on dynamically created user controls

Tags: xaml, mvvm, user-controls, code-behind, dynamically-generated

I am writing a WPF VMMV application.
- I am dynamically loading XAML into the window that contains user control.
- The user control has a textbox besides other simple controls
- The textbox has MouseDoubleClick and KeyDown events

Now, when I load a XAML which has my User Control, the control can be seen (as in the XAML designer), but the events won't work.

I have tried to make the user control with the MVVM pattern instead with code behind. That also does not work. Any experience with this or suggestions?

Comment: Where you wrote your Usercontrol events??

Comment: I wrote them in the usercontrol code-behind.
I also tried to to write them in the viewmodel and connect them by using commands

Comment: please share your code...